# Excel file clean up

Tags: excel

I have an exported excel file where sentences are repeated without a space or period after each sentence. Is there any way to clean this up by removing the repeated sentence without doing this manually ? Here is the sample of sentence

```
Integrase, superantigen-encoding pathogenicity islands SaPIIntegrase, superantigen-encoding pathogenicity islands SaPI
```

Comment: Is the situation always "if there is a repeated phrase, that is all there is"? Are there multiple columns? Is every cell this way, or only some of them? A workable solution will depend on knowing a bit more...

Comment: Floris thank you for replying a) there are no repeated words or phrases. b) Just one column c) every cell is this way..

Comment: and one more question, is it repeated only once?

Comment: Yes.. every cells is supposed to be a sentence but the same sentence is repeated once with no space or period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your sentence is only repeated once, then this will do

`=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)/2)`

Answer (score 1):

Put the following formula in cell B1

```
=LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)/2)
```

Then select B1 and double click the drag handle (little black box in bottom right corner). If I understood your problem correctly you now have "single instances" in column B. Finally, select all of column B, copy, and do Paste Special Values into column A. Lastly, delete column B.